# wpf, c# set Margin.Left of FrameWorkElement using Reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Does anyone know how to set a second-level property using reflection?
In case I want to set the width of lets say a StackPanel, that works fine:

```
PropertyInfo pi = stp.GetType().GetProperty("Width", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (null != pi)
{
  pi.SetValue(stp, Convert.ChangeType("100", pi.PropertyType), null);
}
```

But if I want to set Margin.Left:

```
PropertyInfo pi = stp.GetType().GetProperty("Margin.Left", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (null != pi)
{
  pi.SetValue(stp, Convert.ChangeType("100", pi.PropertyType), null);
}
```

It doesn't work at all. pi is null. I can't get a valid PropertyInfo.
Trying to get a valid FieldInfo fails also:

```
FieldInfo prop = stp.GetType().GetField("Margin.Left", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (null != prop)
{
  prop.SetValue(stp, Convert.ChangeType("20", prop.FieldType));
}
```

Comment: get the Margin value, change its Left member, set it back.

Comment: As a note, it's not necessary to set dependency properties by reflection. If your object is a FrameworkElement, just call `stp.SetValue(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, margin)`.

Comment: Do you really need use reflection? Margin is a public property and you can work with it as usual.

Comment: Using reflection makes it possible to handle it in a general way. Ohterwise I would have to write a lot of code distinguishing what kind of FrameWorkElement it is. Unfortunately not each single kind of FrameWorkElement has a Margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StackPanel` class ha no property named "Margin.Left". It has a `Margin` property that returns a `Thickness`. And `Thickness` is a value type so if you want to change only the left margin, you still need to create a new `Thickness` object that you assign the `Margin` property of the `StackPanel` to:

```
PropertyInfo marginProperty = stp.GetType().GetProperty("Margin", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (null != marginProperty)
{
    Thickness thickness = (Thickness)marginProperty.GetValue(stp);
    marginProperty.SetValue(stp, new Thickness(100d, thickness.Top, thickness.Right, thickness.Bottom));
}
```

Comment: You are correct. Stackpanel has no Property named Margin.Left. Oftherwise it would bei possible to get a valid PropertyInfo. But I can access stp.Margin.Left. I need a general way to set those "two-level" properties like Margin.Left or Padding.Right and so on.

Comment: @manton: Then you need to first get the `PropertyInfo` for the first-level property and then for the second-level property as per the example in my answer.